# Application Insight works fine localhost but in Azure only client side data

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I have a problem with Application Insights that is really similar to this.

[Application Insights - Getting only client side data, no server data.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401584/application-insights-getting-only-client-side-data-no-server-data)

For me however it works fine when i just hit F5 and run the application, i get performance metrics for both client and server side.

However when i deploy the application i dont not get any server side data as far as i can tell. The site runs as a Azure Web App (Web Site). I do get client side data thou.

[image]

Anyone have any tips?

Comment: What SDK version do you use? Bug with similar symptoms was fixed in the latest 0.16.1

Comment: The Nuget packages has 0.16.1.418. Not sure what could be wrong here. It's strange that it works locally but not when deployed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, i'm officially an idiot.

I had a Web.Config transformation that was supposed to only replace an attribute in the  part of Webconfig but it replaced the entire section. And yeah, now it works hehe. Sorry.

Feel free to remove this post since it was clearly just my code / debugging skill that was lacking.

Comment: What configuration let you choose between client side data and erver side data?